# How i can create flex family assets with Rest api OWS

Tags: oracle, api, rest, assets, webcenter-sites

i'm trying to make new application with Oracle Webcenter sites, i'm setting InstallController.java and i need to create flex asset types definitions, but with Rest API you can't create a flex family assets only allows basic assets. how i can create it?

thx

Comment: What is the use of creating a flex family via the API ? I'll see it useful if you'll create many families but as you quite never need to create new families I don't see the point. To my mind creating the flex families in the admin UI is more than enough

Comment: Sure, but if you want to create for example a application (same type that Article sampel demo app) you'll need to call or create the flex assets types and rest api is one option. Inside webcenter we use UI admin always.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code illustrating management of assets via the WebCenter Sites REST API is available in your WebCenter Sites installation directory, in the following paths:

Misc/Samples/WEM Samples/REST API samples/Basic Assets/com/fatwire/rest/samples/basic/ Misc/Samples/WEM Samples/REST API samples/Basic Assets/com/fatwire/rest/samples/flex/

The subfolders basic and flex each contain the following set of files:

```
CreateAsset.java
DeleteAsset.java
ReadAsset.java
UpdateAsset.java
```